# What is difference between element(by.id('username')) and browser.driver.findElement(by.id('username')) while using protractor

Tags: angular, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I wonder as what is the difference between

```
element(by.id('userId')).sendKeys('abc');
```

and

```
browser.driver.findElement(by.id('userId')).sendKeys('abc');
```

when using Protractor.

I have site developed in angular 6 and while writing some UI tests using protractor, I had a hard to figure out that the former is not working for me at all. I had to use the later to get it working and it was only after spending couple of hours I realized it.

Just wondering as what is the difference as I assumed the the `element(by..)` was to be used in angular and examples given on protractor's official website also seem to be using the former option.

In addition, while using `browser.driver` even though I am able to locate elements, but it doesn't wait for the operation to complete. Below code fails after clicking `Login` button. Just wondering as what could be a correct approach here.

```
it('should login', function() {
      browser.get('http://localhost:4200');
      browser.driver.findElement(by.id('userId')).sendKeys('abc');
      browser.driver.findElement(by.id('password')).sendKeys('123');
      browser.driver.findElement(by.id('login-button')).click();
      browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath('//span[text()=\'Maintenance\']')).click();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The former: `element(by.id('userId')).sendKeys('abc')` is an API by protractor while `browser.driver.findElement(by.id('userId')).sendKeys('abc');` is a selenium driver command.

Protractor has wrapped over the selenium driver commands to provide its own API. The APIs provided by protractor wait for any async operations in your angular application to be over (such as "timers", "https requests") before proceeding with next instructions in the queue. On the other hand, driver commands won't wait for async operations to finish.

If the former is not working in your case, then check if you have some timers running in your application.

The way to have timers in angular application is:

```
 this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    // Changes here will not propagate into your view.
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
      // Run inside the ngZone to trigger change detection.
    });
  }, REALLY_LONG_DELAY);
});
```

https://www.protractortest.org/#/timeouts

Comment: Thanks but I don't think any timers are set in the application. Moreover, I tried different pages and timers on each page is hardly possible.

Comment: @apun: Do you have socket connections in your app?

Comment: No, I don't have.

Comment: @apun As far as I know, very long async operations cause protractor to wait forever and then timeout. Reasons for long wait could be: non completing observables, such as: a timer, an Observable listening to an event (could be a DOM event or  a database event, like subscription for changes in a table in DB). Restful HTTP requests time out so that should not be the reason.

Comment: when I click login button above, it takes a while for the service to process. How can I ensure that my code waits till next page loads. Any suggestions?

Comment: @apun The first approach of yours should be to find out why are you unable to use protarctor's `element(by.....)`. Now, if you are sticking with driver commands then they will not wait for page loads to finish and this makes writing tests really really hard. For every line you will write, wait to some hinging element to appear on the page and then find/click/work with the element. For example on next page you want to input in some element, then add a check to wait for that elemnet to appear before giving input.

Comment: I agree. Any suggestions on the approach to find out the root cause for protractor's element not working? Any way to print detailed logs or something?

Comment: Did you try to run the example code of `todo.spec.js` on protractor official website (http://www.protractortest.org/#/) on your local,   If the `todo.spec.js` work on local,  there should be some special things in your website. If not too,  delete protractor clearly and re-install, especially you not use the latest protractor.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Explanation:**

`element(by.id('userId')).sendKeys('abc')` -> To be used when you are automating angular application using protractor.

`browser.driver.findElement(by.id('userId')).sendKeys('abc');` -> To be used when automating non-angular page using protractor.

Hope it helps you..

**Solution**

```
 browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
 browser.get('http://localhost:4200');
 element(by.id('userId')).sendKeys('abc');
 element(by.id('password')).sendKeys('123');
 element(by.id('login-button')).click();
 element(by.xpath('//span[text()=\'Maintenance\']')).click();
```

If you are facing wait issue. Try to add expected wait condition. Refer https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions

Comment: Hope you read my question correctly. The first approach is not working for an angular application. And I don't know why. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below snippet;

```html
browser.wait(function() {
       return element(by.id('userId')).isDisplayed();
    }, 5000);
   element(by.id('userId')).click();.sendKeys()
```

And please check whether any of the functions from  Jasmine APIs are working in your code.
Jasmine API  commands should be working for any angular js application. So, check whether the above commands works when you add **browser.ignoreSynchronization =true** after the **browser.get()** command

This may also be an issue if your jasmine, webdriver is not updated

Good luck!!